# «Городок с населением более 81 тысячи человек». Склонение счетного оборота

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, управление, наречия, счетный-оборот

Правильно ли такое склонение?

Более чем (кто? что?) 81 тысяча человек;
более чем (кого? чего?) 81 тысячи человек;
более чем (кому? чему?) 81 тысяче человек;
более чем (кого? что?) 81 тысячу человек;
более чем с (кем? чем?) 81 тысячей человек;
более чем о (о ком? о чем?) 81 тысяче человек.

Правильны ли два таких варианта?

Городок с населением более чем 81 тысячи человек.
Городок с населением более 81 тысячи человек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет так:

*Городок с населением **более чем 81 тысяча человек.***

*Городок с населением **более 81 тысячи человек**.*

1. Здесь всё очень просто: **БОЛЕЕ и БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ – разные по своей грамматике.** Наречие БОЛЕЕ задает Р.п.  счетному обороту, а  оборот БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ **в управлении вообще не участвует**, его можно опустить.

(1) Городок с населением более **(чего?)** 81 тысячи человек (Р.п.)

(2) Городок с населением **(более чем)** 81 тысяча человек (форма И.п. и В.п.)

2. А какое же слово  тогда управляет падежом во втором случае?  Примеры можно посмотреть в Справочнике по пунктуации. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68

Из них видно, что управление  в предложении строится **без участия оборота** БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ.

3. **Примеры:**

Таким образом,  тайна была сохранена (более чем) **полудюжиною** заговорщиков.  Т.п. беспредложный.

Егоров вообще не любил, когда начальник розыскного отдела отлучался (более чем) **на сутки.** В.п. с предлогом НА.

На снимке (более чем) **столетней давности** был изображен коллектив только что открывшегося мясного храма.  Р.п. беспредложный.

Деревня была уже (не более чем) **в двухстах шагах**. П.п. с предлогом В.

Comment: Возможно, хорошо  бы оформить так: "более 81-й тысячи человек".

Comment: Не-не, Инна, так не пойдет. Наше числительное (восемьдесят одна тысяча) — количественное (сколько?), а наращения требуются только к порядковым числительным: восемьдесят **первая** (какая?) тысяча. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99

Answer (score 3):

[**бо́лее**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5&all=x), ***сравнит. ст.; наречие***
**1.** =Больше (1-2 зн.). *Ваш шпиц — прелестный шпиц, не более напёрстка* (Грибоедов).
**Более чем...**
**I. *в зн. нареч.*** Совершенно, в высшей степени, очень. Более чем интересно. *Ваше выступление более чем возмутительно.*
**II. *в зн. частицы.*** *Это странно. — Более чем странно.*

*Восемьдесят одна тысяча человек* — это счетный оборот, который изменяется по падежам (кроме, конечно, слова "человек") и **весь** является одним членом предложения.

Наречие **более** требует после себя родительного падежа (связь — [управление](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/782-32_osobennosti_upravleniya_v_russkom_yazyke.html)):
более (чего?) миллиона книг; более (чего?) всего; более (чего?) десяти тысяч рублей; более (кого?) трех тысяч рабочих; *более* (кого?) *восьмидесяти одной тысячи человек.*

Присутствие же **более чем** в счетном обороте на его обычное склонение не влияет:
И. п. кто? — более чем восемьдесят одна тысяча человек;
Д. п. кому? — более чем восьмидесяти одной тысяче человек;
Т. п. кем? — более чем восьмьюдесятью одной тысячей человек.

Получается, что правильно надо писать так:
**Городок с населением более 81** (восьмидесяти одной) **тысячи человек.

Городок с населением более чем 81** (восемьдесят одна) **тысяча человек.**

Города с населением [более миллиона](https://geo.koltyrin.ru/goroda_millionniki.php) человек.
Города с населением более чем миллион человек.